# how to show div on under button on onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

From this code i have three button ,now i cliked ** Reply button 1** means i want to show one textarea for bottom of the button( Reply button 1).else i have to select  Reply button 2 means i want show the textarea for under this  Reply button 2..i don't know how to do.i am new developer please help me some one

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//1?>" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 1</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//2?>" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 2</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//3?>" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 3</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

After click that button i want to show this

```html
  <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
```

Comment: All are span ,If you include any div inside it, All other next span ll be down..Not vertical..Better you have to use div(with style table) or table.

Comment: @nisar,see my updated code,i have like ,how to do my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this should help you surely. You need not use seperate ids for each

**JS**

```
$('.reply-btn').on('click',function() {
  $(this).closest('.comment').next('.reply').html("<div><textarea class='the-new-com'></textarea></div>");
})
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//1?>" id="reply-btn-1" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 1</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="reply"></div>


<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//2?>"id="reply-btn-2" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 2</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="reply"></div>

<div class="comment">
  <div class="img-thumbnail">
    <img class="avatar" alt="" src="../TV/dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="comment-block">
    <div class="comment-arrow"></div>
    <span class="comment-by">
      <strong>Kani</strong>
      <span class="pull-right">
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" rel="<?php echo $com['id']//3?>" id="reply-btn-3" class="reply-btn"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i> Reply button 3</a>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
    <span class="date pull-right">19-Apr-2016 </span>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="reply"></div>
```

Comment: i tried ur code see my screenshot,it is not working perfetcly

Comment: Are you using bootstrap columns. Because that might be the reason a new div in not coming under the reply opition

Comment: textarea open on down of the comment box

Comment: i tried this also  $(this).after("<div class='comment'><textarea class='the-new-com'></textarea></div>");   but getting same ans

Comment: I edited the code try the new one. Idea to to add a textarea in a new div that is created after the comment box. you may need to reposition the div according to your placement of textarea. Try this and let me know if it helped

Comment: see now my screenshot,i want like 1 screenshoot,but still i am getting 2 nd screenshot

Comment: its not the same code I changes the reply-div position outside of your comment box. I can understand its difficult to make out though :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109623/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-mani-m).

Comment: Finally i got my requirement

Answer (score 1):

use this below jQuery...and also include this below js library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$('.reply-btn').on('click',function() {
  $(this).after("<div><textarea class='addedText'></textarea></div>");
});
```

Comment: it will open inside the comment box,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('div [id |=reply-btn]').on('click',function() {

  $(this).after("<div><textarea class='the-new-com'></textarea></div>");

});
```

[https://jsbin.com/](https://jsbin.com/jayeye/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: how do you want , one textarea on reply button?  then check this https://jsbin.com/jayeye/edit?html,js,output